# The existence of primitive algebraic units modulo 3

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, roots-of-unity

Consider the problem of computing

$$\sqrt{2} \mod 3 $$

Whereas we seek a number $n$ such that $n^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ and furthermore it is known that both $n$ and $2n$ will satisfy this property, thus the smaller, while maintaining positive coefficients of the 'n' should be selected.

It is apparent that this problem has no obvious initial solution however by observing:

$$ 2 \equiv -1 \rightarrow \sqrt{2} \equiv \sqrt{-1} \equiv i \mod 3 $$

and of course

$$ (2i)^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3$$

but based on our initial stipulation

$$ i \equiv \sqrt{2} \mod 3$$

since it features a smaller  positive coefficient.

From here we can then consider the complex integers modulo 3 which are numbers of the form

$$ a + bi$$

such that $ a,b \in \lbrace{0,1,2}\rbrace $

Again attempting to compute square roots in this environment reveals

$$ \sqrt{0} \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{1} \equiv 1 \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{2} \equiv i \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{i} \equiv 1 + 2i \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{1 + i} \equiv \sqrt{1 + i} \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{2i} \equiv 1 + i \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{1 + 2i} \equiv (1 + i)\sqrt{1 + i} \mod 3$$
$$ \sqrt{2 + 2i} \equiv i\sqrt{1 + i} \mod 3$$

Notice how all the square roots can be defined in terms of $0,1,2,i, \sqrt{1 + i} $

This suggests that:

$ \sqrt{1 + i} $ is another 'natural' unit modulo 3 and therefore we can declare

$$ \sqrt{1 + i} \equiv i_2 $$

whereas the numbers mod 3 now take on the form:

$$ (a_1 + a_2 i_1) + (a_3 + a_4 i_1 ) i_2 $$

where

$$i_1^2 \equiv 2 \mod 3 \ \ and \ \ i_2^2 \equiv 1 + i \mod 3$$

I wonder whether by repeatedly taking square roots of these numbers, will an infinite chain of 'unique' units be generated? Or does it stop and there are only a finite number of

$$i_1 , i_2 ... i_n $$

that need to be defined so that:

$$ \sqrt{((...((a_1 + a_2 i_1) + (a_3 + a_4i_1)i_2) + ((a_5 + a_6 i_1) + (a_7 + a_8i_1)i_2)i_3 ... )))} $$

are all defined.

An environment modulo R for a set of units $\lbrace 1,i_1, i_2 ... i_n \rbrace$ is defined as the set of all linear combinations using $\lbrace{0,1,2... R-1} \rbrace$ for coefficients of the set of all product combinations from the set of units.

Note the size of environments are $R^{2^n}$ where $n$ is the number of units present.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sqrt{2} \pmod 3$?

Comment: I'm asking for an equivalent expression to $\sqrt{2}$ I think the question explains itself through its technique of resolving this normally 'undefined' term

Comment: At no point have you defined what those combination of symbols means. As such, applying steps like $\sqrt{2} \equiv \sqrt{-1} \pmod 3$ have absolutely no meaning.

Comment: Alright I will make it explicit what my definition is in the question however I do hope that at least intuitively what I'm attempting to convey is present :)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese please check if this new edit is understandeable

Comment: What is "an environment" for you? A ring? It looks like you are on your way in constructing the field of nine elements. But it also feels like you think of mod as a remainder operator instead of the more useful congruence, and that is getting on the way of you defining things "properly"?

Comment: I think you would like to have a glance at the theory of finite fields. :)

Comment: Sorry, I missed some of the revisions. Seconding what awllower suggests. You can find all those square roots in appropriate finite fields. (+1) for work and description of goals shown.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how so? Based on what I read the Integers modulo 3 form a finite field, in the sense that there is well defined addition, multiplication, subtraction, division, and the field is finite in its set of elements however as has been made clear with these comments the integers modulo 3 is not well defined in terms of algebraic operations such as extracting square roots (namely 2). However by extending it to include i, we now introduce 1 additional undefined square root (1+ i) namely. I am curious is it possible to extend this field a finite number of times before it becomes closed?

Comment: Also, an environment modulo 3 for a set of units $\lbrace 1,i_1, i_2 ... i_n \rbrace $ for me is defined as the set of all linear combinations involving (0,1,2) from the set of all product combinations from the set of units.

Comment: I think I get the idea. You get a chain of finite fields of three, nine, $81$, $6561$ elements and so on, when you keep adding more and more square roots to the environment. The process never stops in the sense that when you create a new square root to the system you also create new elements that won't have a square root. If I think of a satisfactory way of describing this without rewriting a textbook of finite fields I will do so. Thinking...

Comment: Yea you got the idea. Now the problem I have is how to prove that this chain indeed never stops. Or (in some freakish way that math is capable of being) if it does actually stop: when, and why?

Comment: Seriously: learn about the theory behind finite fields. You will get to the heart of what's going on, this problem will be trivial, and you'll see much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have determined that what I have been calling an 'environment' is indeed a finite field (as per popular suggestion the comments).

Furthermore given that it is a finite field that means the theorem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Algebraic_closure

Proves that it indeed cannot be closed algebraically and therefore if we consider other operations besides square roots but rather the inverse to any polynomial then indeed an infinitely large set of units will be generated.